# How to make an image screen-wide with Bootstrap?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have tried to nest the image in a `jumbotron` and a `container` but to no avail. Here's my latest effort that didn't quite work out:

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="full-width-div">
    <div class="col-md-12">
      <img src="http://i665.photobucket.com/albums/vv18/luckycharm_boy/Miami-Skyline-HD-Wallpapers1.jpeg_zps18p2ssu0.gif" alt=“90s Video Game Aesthetic Miami Skyline Photo”/>
    </div>
  </div>  
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you are missing class `container` to wrap it, and add `img-responsive` to `img`

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-12">
      <img class="img-responsive" src="http://i665.photobucket.com/albums/vv18/luckycharm_boy/Miami-Skyline-HD-Wallpapers1.jpeg_zps18p2ssu0.gif" alt=“90s Video Game Aesthetic Miami Skyline Photo”/>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**UPDATE** (taken from comments)

that's because your image is smaller than the container 1024px(img) VS 1170px(in `md` view) so either

- use a larger image like [here](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/XdQBVE)

  or
- set `width:100%`  to `img` and also remove class `img-responsive` for larger screens (media queries)

Comment: I have already tried it, the image ends up on the left side of the window.

Comment: can you give a link to the site?

Comment: I see perfectly centered, left side of the window how?

Comment: When I go on full page view the image is slightly aligned to the left and the image is not stretched out across the whole width of the window.

Comment: again completely centered, using FF, see [here](http://easycaptures.com/fs/uploaded/935/6528287525.png), unless you need `col-lg-12` for viewing in a large screen

Comment: tried `col-lg-12` too, still looks like [this](http://easycaptures.com/2667293273) in full page view

Comment: that's because your image is smaller than the `container` 1024px VS 1170px(in `md` view) so either use a larger image like [here](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/XdQBVE) or set `width:100%` for larger screens (media queries)  to `img` and also removing class `img-responsive`

Answer (score 0):

Rows must be placed within a .container (fixed-width) or .container-fluid (full-width) for proper alignment and padding.

Use rows to create horizontal groups of columns.

Content should be placed within columns, and only columns may be immediate children of rows.

You can specify for screen width also.

```
For larger screens you can use col-lg-12 --> (≥1200px)
For medium screens you can use col-md-12 --> Desktops (≥992px)
For small  screens you can use col-sm-12 --> (≥768px)
For extra small screens you can use col-xs-12 --> Phones (<768px)
```

here is the working example : https://jsfiddle.net/melih193/8wzg9qfL/2/